# HTTP Basic Authentication for specific domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains `example.com` and `example2.com`. Both domains are pointing to same server and I want to enable http authentication for `example2.com` visitors **ONLY**. How can I do that?

Here is my current code and asks username/password from all visitors:

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Require Authentication for Example2.com"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/<hostname>/httpdocs/<passwd file>
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this using an `if directive`. So if the `{HTTP_HOST}` is equal to `example2.com`, then use authentication:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example2.com'">
    ....
</if>
```

So simply place your authentication code within that `if directive`. Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.